# I am trying to update status to twitter using twitter4j jar but it does not work

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Logcat:

```
12-06 09:23:25.673: D/final(537): caught
12-06 09:23:27.003: D/userName(537): sayemsiam
12-05 12:42:20.783: W/System.err(588): 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
12-05 12:42:20.783: W/System.err(588): error - Read-only application cannot POST
12-05 12:42:20.783: W/System.err(588): request - /1/statuses/update.json
```

i have set read,write permission in my application settings though it gives.

Here is my whole code.

```
public class TweetActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        // configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        // configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);

        CustomAsyncTask cm = new CustomAsyncTask();
        cm.execute(new String[] { "df" });
    }

    private class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String CALLBACK_URI = "http://myapp.com";
            String CONSUMER_KEY = "********************";
            String CONSUMER_SECRET = "************************";
            String ACCESS_TOKEN = "*******************";
            String ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "***********************";
            AccessToken ac = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
            Log.d("robin", "caught");
            // Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();

            // Twitter twitter = new
            // TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance(ac);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(ac);
            Log.d("sayfsdem", "caught");

            try {
                twitter4j.Status status = twitter
                        .updateStatus("tihs sw th aa updatein");
                Log.d("status", status.toString());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("final", "caught");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Log.d("userName", twitter.getScreenName());
                // Log.d("password",twitter.getFavorites()());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d("illesayem", "caught");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.d("fdfds", "caught");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "dfs";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }
}
```

Only i can see that it can read the screen name though i have set read write permission in my application settings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What line of your code generates the error?

Comment: Are you using twitter4j 2.2.5 or above? Twitter requires secure connections now, and anything below 2.2.5 does not connect securely.

Comment: I have tested using twitter4j 2.2.6 snapshot but same problem.

Comment: Have you checked the clock is in sync?

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue when i changed Twitter Api Access permissions.

```
Regenerating the Access Token solved it
```

Comment: Use SocialAuth Android https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/    . Additionally don't post same message twice on twitter

Answer (score 0):

You have to go onto your Application on the Twitter developer website and change your apps permission to Read & Write.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if the following works, I've had trouble using twitter4j.auth.AccessToken directly:

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET(;
configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

twitter.whatever(...);
```