# Why this error ' - Read-only application cannot POST '

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Logcat:

```
12-05 23:37:01.721:W/System.err(534):  401:Authentication credentials  (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid     conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
12-05 23:37:01.721: W/System.err(534): 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
12-05 23:37:01.721: W/System.err(534): error - Read-only application cannot POST
12-05 23:37:01.721: W/System.err(534): request - /1/statuses/update.json
```

Though i can read the screen name by (getScreenName() function) and set read,write permission to my twitter application , it gives the above logcat.And i am using twitter4j jar file.

Comment: Looks like you didn't include the authentication data for an account. Post your code.

Comment: Here is my full code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382021/i-am-trying-to-update-status-to-twitter-using-twitter4j-jar-but-it-does-not-work

Comment: Please don't repost the same question.

Comment: But i did not get answer at that time and really stuck with this problem . i seen all documentation to do code right way.But it does not work

Comment: That question is only 11 hours old. Read [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) about what to do when you don't get an answer.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

- Login in your app: http://dev.twitter.com/apps
- In the `Settings` tab, change the `Application type` to `Read, Write and Access direct messages`
- In the `Reset keys` tab, press the `Reset` button, update the consumer key and secret in your application accordingly.

It looks like that resetting the keys force the change to your application type to take effect.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but resetting my consumer key and secret didn't fix this problem for me trying to send Direct Messages to people, I still got the "Read-only application cannot POST", despite restarting my application, manually revoking the App and authorising it again, and re-running the test.  Eventually I recreated my access token ("Recreate my access token" button on the App 'Details' pane on dev.twitter.com) and the Direct Message could be sent.  I can't say whether this was required, or if the Consumer key/secret reset worked and I simply didn't wait long enough for it to take effect.

Comment: After you modify your permissions, you have to regenerate the access-token and access-token-secret.

Answer (score 24):

## 2022 UPDATE

all previously posted solutions don't work anymore. Here is the current solutiuon:

1. select your app
2. edit auth settings
3. enable OAuth1
4. select required permissions
5. Enter the call back URL (it can be anything)
6. **Re-generate API Token** (NOTE: you must do this or this process will not work)

## dashboard (step 1+2)

[image]

## settings (step 3+4)

[image]

Comment: This is the only way to go since 2022. Forget all other explanations.

Comment: Now at the end of 2022 it's OAuth 2.0 but everything else in this answer is still accurate, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://dev.twitter.com/ -> My Applications -> "go to your current application" -> Setting -> Give the permission for "Read, Write and Direct Access" -> Save it. After that uninstall your project from emulator or device, -> Clean project -> Run Project.

Hope it will helpful. try this one:

Answer (score 3):

Steps to follow for this problem.

Login with

https://dev.twitter.com/apps
and go to settings

and Change the permission `Read-only` to

`Read, Write and Access direct messages`

and update page. and if in case not able to update then Re-Create the Token and try again problem will be solved..

Answer (score 2):

May be issue with your twitter application:
Write Permission may remaining is it creates problem:

Go to https://dev.twitter.com/ -> My Applications -> "go to your current application" -> Setting -> Give the permission for "Read, Write and Direct Access" -> Save it. After that uninstall your project from emulator or device, -> Clean project -> Run Project.

Hope it will helpful:

Answer (score 2):

You also have to revoke your old permission after you reset your permission.

1. Go to 
   https://twitter.com/settings/applications
2. Find your app and you will see that it has read permission
3. Revoke the access

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Hemangi answer, you dont have to regenerate the consumer keys and secret. In your twitter developer portal go to the *Keys and Tokens* tab and check the access token

[image]

If it says created with only Read Only permissions, regenerate the Access Token and Secret and update the same in your code.

[image]

Comment: i did it but created same... just read only permission

Comment: @AteşDanış you have to give write permissions to your project and then regenerate the tokens. Go to Your Project>Settings> User Authentication Settings >App permissions. Change it from Read to Read and Write

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your application with twitter to get your consumer-secret key?

Comment: Yes i have registered the app to get consumer-secrect key

Comment: Here u can find the whole code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382021/i-am-trying-to-update-status-to-twitter-using-twitter4j-jar-but-it-does-not-work

Comment: I am really stuck with this.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [portal](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/)
2. **Option**: Projets & Apps tab.
3. Inside this Option, go Setting, the App Permissions and change `Read-only` to `Read + Write + Post Read Direct Messages`
4. **Save**
5. Finally, go to the `Keys and Tokens tab` and regenerate only the Access token and Secret