# rtweet: post_follow function returns read only error

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I recently implemented the `rtweet` package to begin pulling and posting Twitter data. The `get_` family of functions work fine but when I run a `post_` function, in this case `post_follow`, I get a read-only error. See below:

```
 > rtweet::post_follow(user = 'hadleywickham')
 $request
 [1] "/1.1/friendships/create.json"

 $error
 [1] "Read-only application cannot POST."
```

I checked to make sure my tweets are not protected.

Comment: Did you try the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567698/11742753

Comment: thank you this was super helpful!